# Apache POI: How to set THIS_YEAR filter in row label date of a pivot

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a pivot in excel using apache poi.
My requirement is to apply the Date Filter (THIS YEAR) i.e to show only current year dates in the date row label in the pivot.

**Problem:** Below the reproducible code that generates output excel file with "THIS_YEAR" filter applied to the date column but for some reason, it's not showing any data.

Below is the code to generate the output.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreatePivotTableFilter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("M\\/d\\/yy"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Date", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }

   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2020, 0, 2), 2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2020, 0, 1), 4d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 1d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 7d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1), 5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1), 5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 2d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)rowData[c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
    }
   }

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference("A1:D9", 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), 
    new CellReference("F4"));

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);
 
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);

   CTPivotFilters filters = CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();
   CTPivotFilter filter = filters.addNewFilter();
   filter.setId(0);
   filter.setFld(2);
   filter.setType(STPivotFilterType.THIS_YEAR);
   CTFilterColumn filterColumn = filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   filterColumn.setColId(0);
   CTFilters ctFilters = filterColumn.addNewFilters();
   ctFilter.addNewFilter().setVal("This Year Filter");
    
   //set filters to pivot table definition
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

**Output generated by code**

[image]

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way dealing with the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes is creating whatever one wants using `Excel`'s `GUI`, then unzipping the resulting `*.xlsx` file and having a look at the `XML` what the `GUI` has created.

In that case in `xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml` we find:

```
...
<filters>
 <filter fld="2" type="thisYear" id="0">
  <autoFilter>
   <filterColumn colId="0">
    <dynamicFilter type="thisYear"/>
   </filterColumn>
  </autoFilter>
 </filter>
</filters>
...
```

So `filterColumn` does not contain `<filters><filter ...>` but contains `dynamicFilter` of `type` `thisYear`.

So your code would must be:

```
...
   CTPivotFilters filters = CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();
   CTPivotFilter filter = filters.addNewFilter();
   filter.setId(0);
   filter.setFld(2);
   filter.setType(STPivotFilterType.THIS_YEAR);
   CTFilterColumn filterColumn = filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   filterColumn.setColId(0);
   CTDynamicFilter ctDynamicFilter = filterColumn.addNewDynamicFilter();
   ctDynamicFilter.setType(STDynamicFilterType.THIS_YEAR);
    
   //set filters to pivot table definition
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);
...
```

Unfortunately there is not any `API` documentation of `ooxml-schemas` public available. So if we need it, we need to download `ooxml-schemas` sources from `maven`. Then we can create a `API` documentation using `javadoc`. There then we can find fields and methods of `CTFilterColumn` for example.

Comment: Thank you for being so prompt and active for apache poi questions. Your answers across the community have helped me a lot in creating very advanced excel pivots.